# Value of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject - React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I save a username in async-storage and it's saved very well I can see it in profile screen I get it there

and in profile screen, I want to update this value I use `mergeItem()` method but after call it I got this error

> Error: Value name1 of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to
>   JSONObject

here's how i save username in Async-Storage

```
 <TextInput
        onChangeText={value => this.setState({userName: value})}
        value={userName}
 />

createUserDatabase = async ()=>{

     const {userName} = this.state;
    ...
     let nameStorage = await AsyncStorage.setItem('username', userName);
    ...
}
```

Here's how I update it

```
  saveData = async () => {
    const {username} = this.state;
    console.log('saveData-username:', username); // i got the new name here 'name1'
    try {
      let multi = await AsyncStorage.mergeItem('username', username).then(() =>
        console.log('then statment'),
      );
      console.log('multi', multi);
    } catch (e) {
      // error
      console.log('error:', e);
    }
  };
```

Comment: how was this resolved?